# POST never create embedded relation on OneToMany

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, denormalization

I have four entities represented like this:

```
Book
  |_ BookAuthorRelation
      |_ Author
      |_ [AuthorRoles]
```

The relation between Book and BookAuthorRelation is a OneToMany.
I want to create a BookAuthorRelation when I post a Book.

```json
{
  ...
  "authors": [
    {
      "author": "/api/authors/1ec71139-3d12-6440-896f-d193032813a2",
      "roles": ["/api/author_roles/1ec7109b-2bae-699a-af25-255aeb21a456"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I use the Groups attribute (`post:book`) and `cascade={"persist"}`, but it doesn't work.
After a long time of debug, I think the entity of this relation (BookAuthorRelation) is created (the PHP object, it's not persisted in database), but the parent entity (Book) is never populated with it.

This my entities (I remove the unnecessary code as ApiFilters, others properties and relations, etc):

```php
// Book.php

#[ApiResource(
    denormalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['post:book'],
        'enable_max_depth' => true,
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['get:book']],
)]
class Book
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=BookAuthorRelation::class, mappedBy="book", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    #[Groups(['get:book', 'post:book'])]
    #[MaxDepth(2)]
    private Collection $authors;

    ...
}
```

```php
// BookAuthorRelation.php

#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        'get',
        'post',
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get',
        'put',
        'delete',
        'patch',
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['book-author-roles']],
)]
class BookAuthorRelation
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Book::class, inversedBy="authors")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    #[Groups(['book-author-roles'])]
    private Book $book;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Author::class, inversedBy="books")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    #[Groups(['book-author-roles', 'get:book', 'post:book'])]
    private Author $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=AuthorRole::class)
     */
    #[Groups(['book-author-roles', 'get:book', 'post:book'])]
    private Collection $roles;

    ...
}
```

When I try a PATCH on the created Book with a complete BookAuthorRelation, it's the same issue:

```json
{
  ...
  "authors": [
    {
      "book": "/api/books/1ec7bd00-42db-6016-b395-4df71068d6b1",
      "author": "/api/authors/1ec71139-3d12-6440-896f-d193032813a2",
      "roles": ["/api/author_roles/1ec7109b-2bae-699a-af25-255aeb21a456"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Other types of relations seems to work.
Where is my mistake?

---

PHP 8.0

api-platform 2.6.8

Symfony 5.4.2

Comment: The `book`property in your `BookAuthorRelation` is lacking the `post:book` group. Shouldn't that be necessary to actually set the relation on the object although it is created in a nested post?